# Why does arguments in Javascript return [object Arguments] when using console.log?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
//simple function with parameters and variable
        function thirdfunction(a,b,c,d){
            console.log("the value of a is: " + a);
            console.log("the value of b is: " + b);
            console.log("the value of c is: " + c);
            console.log("the value of d is: " + d);
            console.log("the arguments for each values are: " + arguments);
            console.log("the number of arguments passed are: " + arguments.length);
        }

        console.log("no parameter values are passed");
        thirdfunction();

        console.log("only a and b parameter values are passed");
        thirdfunction(1,2);
```

However when the values passed in `arguments` are not displayed if I concatenate the text `the arguments for each values are:`. Why is that?

The output I have from Google's console is as follows when concatenating;

```
no parameter values are passed
the value of a is: undefined
the value of b is: undefined
the value of c is: undefined
the value of d is: undefined
the arguments for each values are: [object Arguments]
the number of arguments passed are: 0
only a and b parameter values are passed
the value of a is: 1
the value of b is: 2
the value of c is: undefined
the value of d is: undefined
the arguments for each values are: [object Arguments]
the number of arguments passed are: 2
```

The following values are passed when I don't concatenate.

```
no parameter values are passed
the value of a is: undefined
the value of b is: undefined
the value of c is: undefined
the value of d is: undefined
[]
the number of arguments passed are: 0
only a and b parameter values are passed
the value of a is: 1
the value of b is: 2
the value of c is: undefined
the value of d is: undefined
[1, 2]
the number of arguments passed are: 2
```

**EDIT**

Not sure why the question got down voted but the problem I have is that when I use the statement `console.log("the arguments for each values are: " + arguments);` the output in the console is `console.log("the arguments for each values are: " + arguments);` however if I pass the statement `console.log(arguments);` the output in the console is `[]` or `[1, 2]`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem...

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Where is the arguments variable set? Also the arguments passed to the function will default to undefined if not set.

Comment: @hsmoore arguments does not need to be set, it is available in all functions, it is an array representing all arguments called with the function.

Comment: @hsmoore.com - As per my example if I do `console.log("the arguments for each values are: " + arguments);` the response returned is [object Arguments] whilst if I do ` console.log("the arguments for each values are: " + arguments);` I get `[]` or `[1, 2]`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - A note here, `arguments` is not an array, that's why it only shows `[object Arguments]`.

Comment: @* - Be great if people could advise why they downvote my question and I'll rectify mistakes I have made.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - They downvoted because it is difficult to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: @Derek - How can I improve it? Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Maybe changing the wording of the title? I am not sure because at least I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @Derek - Changed the title and added more information. Be great if StackOverflow had people comment why they down vote. The fact that you can down vote without actually advising what is wrong with the question should lead to down voting the person down voting the poster of the question.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Sometimes in SO people just like to click the downvote button on questions because it won't deduct any reputation. `:(`

Comment: @Derek - If they don't provide any context to down voting their reputation should be downgraded. if they do provide context, they should gain reputation. It is unfair to the person posting the question to be down voted if there is no context being provided. I know I'm not a mind reader. Hopefully they change the policy.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - You can suggest that in the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `console.log("..." + arguments)` it will force conversion of `arguments` into string. Since [arguments is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), its string representation is `[object Arguments]`. If you instead want to display contents of that object, try passing it without concatenation:

```
console.log("the arguments for each values are: ", arguments);
```